# Azure App service gives default page after re-running ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am new to Azure Cloud and started working on App services. I created an app service through ARM templates from Azure Devops. Once done, I get the default page which is expected
[image: Default Page]

Now, I deploy a sample react application to the App service and I see the application. However, when I re-run the ARM template, it takes me back to the default page. I am unable to understand why a re-run of ARM takes me back to the default page instead of my react app.

What can I do to have my react app up even after ARM template re-run? Is there any point I am missing?

Comment: Linux Or Windows platform ?

Comment: @JasonPan Windows Platform. Forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous app service and re-did everything. Now, my application stays as is even after re-deploying the ARM template. Not sure what went wrong, the first time